# Passing JSON object from php to JS via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to pass a JSON object from a php script to a Javascript file with Ajax. The code below worked for a simple string, but I am now trying to amend it to work with multiple strings contained within a JSON object. I have pasted extracts of each file below. What am I doing wrong?

This is a extract from the html/javascript file which is creating the request...

```
  function retrieveAircraftInfo(str) {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0) { 
     document.aircraftRegForm.aircraftManufacturer.value="";
     return;
     }


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
                var aircraftDataJSON = xmlhttp.responseText.evalJSON();
                document.aircraftRegForm.aircraftManufacturer.value = aircraftDataJSON.manufacuter;
                document.aircraftRegForm.aircraftType.value = aircraftDataJSON.type;
                document.aircraftRegForm.aircraftPopularName.value = aircraftDataJSON.popularName;
                document.aircraftRegForm.aircraftGenericName.value = aircraftDataJSON.genericName;
           }
     }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","scraper.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

This is an extract from the php file which is doing the database search:

```
$aircraftDataArray = array("manufacturer" => $extractedManufacturer,
    "type" => $extractedType,
    "popularName" => $extractedPopularName,
    "genericName" => $extractedGenericName);

echo json_encode($aircraftDataArray);
```

Comment: You mean `json_encode()` right?

Comment: ah yes - that is one mistake. [I have updated code] But still doesn't work. Is it something to do with setting a content type to application/JSON? I have seen this mentioned somewhere but don't know where to put this.

Comment: Calls to `header` can go anywhere before any output (like `echo`).  In the case of a Content-Type header you can set it as soon as you know what the content type is going to be. If you are only ever returning JSON, it can be the first line of the script if you want.

Comment: What is not working? Where is `.evalJSON()` (Prototype?) coming from? `manufacturer != manufacuter`

Comment: Ah got it working...I needed JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: You're also going to want this: if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200).  The readyState just tells you that the server has finished processing the request--not that the request was successful, e.g. the sever looked for the page you requested, but couldn't find it so the server returned a 404 error.  And if you use jQuery, you don't have to worry about all the cross browser junk.

Comment: JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); is not supported by all browsers. If you need support for legacy browsers, you may try $.parseJSON (jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try

var aircraftDataJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);

Otherwise, check in the console of the developer tools if PHP returns some error.

Your JS example worked for me with JSON.parse